# Error crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated in debugger tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a website and I finished the HTML and CSS file, and I wanted to test it. But the error started to appear in **both** Chrome and Visual Studio Code.

Chrome:
[image]
VSC:
[image]

I thought I have to install WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) but WSL is already installed in my computer, find every answer in Stack Overflow but the answer doesn't fix the error. I did find on how to install the LxssManager.dll service, but every hour I haven't find the service yet.

[image]

P.S. I am just a newbie developer, and I want to know how to build a website.